# Virtualbox file sharing is not working

Tags: networking, virtualbox, samba

I have installed Samba network sharing application.My folder in Linux looks like
[image]

I want to share it with my Windows 10 on virtualbox.But when I opt for networks
[image]

But the folder is empty.Where is my Linux folder?It has not been recognized, why?
My firewall is not active

```
 sudo ufw status 
Status: inactive
```

This is my network configuration in Windows
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good tutorial on creating SAMBA shares at [this location](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!)

The basic steps are

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install samba
sudo smbpasswd -a <user_name>
```

after which the tutorial goes into sharing the file from the command line.  I instead shared my files from nautilus, and had good results.

[image]

There is a line that I have had to add to my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file to get this to work with Windows 10 guests:

```
[global]

encrypt passwords = true
```

After which I did need to restart SAMBA with

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: I have followed the instructions,but it is the same.I will take a look at VIrtualBox setup,something is wrong.

Comment: If you are running a firewall, such as GUFW, ensure that you have the appropriate ports open for SAMBA

Comment: How to see if I am running firewall?

Comment: try `sudo ufw status`